# Need USB-C splitter that will power XP-13 laptop AND connect external drive

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, external-hard-drive

My Dell XP13 laptop has two USB-C ports. I use one for power and the other for my second monitor. Now I've purchased an external drive and I can't find a USB-C splitter that will allow me to charge the computer and connect the the external drive. I need the second USB-C port for the monitor, so I need a solution to connect both external drive and power into the the reaming port. Is this possible?

Comment: The solution is to use the same port you're using for the monitor with a simple adapter cable or docking station that provides USB ports.

Comment: Thanks, I ordered a hub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for USB hub power delivery.

For example https://www.startech.com/en-gb/usb-hubs/5g2a2cpdb-usb-c-hub